# Cannot connect to view/table, because view/table name too long

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to connect to an SQL Server through Microsoft Access (by clicking on external data > OBDC Database > Make a connection to the datasource... > open DSN located on drive > click on file/view name > click on OK)

I get the error message that the table name is too long.

Unfortunately, changing the table name is currently not an option (because the admin is unavailable).

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: What is the table name?  Have you tried creating a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/303968)?

Comment: thanks. Pass-through query solved my problem :)